# Delphi TImage Loading GIF Bad Qality

Tags: delphi, vcl, timage

While a process is running in the background, I show a loading animation on the screen. But the GIF looks very bad quality. How can I fix this problem?

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg, Vcl.ExtCtrls,
  Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  var
    sFile: string;
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;
  aGIF: TGIFImage;
  bmp:TBitmap;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.FormShow(Sender: TObject);

begin
  aGIF := TGIFImage.Create;
  aGIF.LoadFromFile(sFile);
  aGIF.Animate := True;
  Image1.Picture.Assign(aGIF);
  aGIF.Free;
end;

end.
```

[image]

Comment: Can't you use the `TActivityIndicator`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I want use loading GIF animate.

Comment: Are you using any VCL Style? The form looks darker than standard (like there would be an overlay) and the form header is not the standard color. Is the GIF available for download for testing?

Comment: Did you check whether the gif itself is of a good quality...?

Comment: Did you try with another GIF? What if you run the same GIF in another (not Delphi) program?

Comment: Based on the image provided it seems that this is a low resolution GIF stretched to much larger size. Since GIF's are raster based images stretching them will cause them to look pix-elated. You should find suitable larger GIF to use instead of this one. That way your image wont be garbled due to stretching to much larger size than original is.

Comment: In fact, three forms are shown. The main form shown first. The second form shown is transparent and has a black background. The third shown form contains GIF. It has a transparent background in the third form. The GIFs I use are normally good quality and large enough in size. I think the problem is that the background of the form in which the GIF is located is transparent.

Comment: Why three forms? Are you using the second form to make your main form appear darker while GIF animation is being played?

Comment: Yes, I use second form for appear darker.